# Get component layer from MixtureSameFamily distribution layer - Tensorflow Probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm making a Mixture Density Network model class in Tensorflow Probability that combines a fully connected left-hand side with a distribution layer right-hand. I want to instantiate the class with the MixtureSameFamily distribution layer, which itself is comprised of a component layer (say, IndependentNormal or MultivariateNormalTriL), and be able to access the component layer information from the distribution layer object.

Currently, I have:

```
def __init__(self, K, X, Y, distribution_layer, component_layer):

    ...

    self.dist = distribution_layer
    self.params_size = self.dist.params_size(
                        self.K,
                        component_params_size=component_layer.params_size([self.M,self.P])
                        )
    ...

    return

...

input_comp_layer = tfp.layers.IndependentNormal([M,P])
input_dist_layer = tfp.layers.MixtureSameFamily(K, input_comp_layer)
A = MDN(K, X, Y, input_dist_layer, input_comp_layer)
```

Whereas I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
def __init__(self, K, X, Y, distribution_layer):

    ...

    self.dist = distribution_layer
    self.params_size = self.dist.component_layer.params_size(self.K, [self.M,self.P])

    ...

    return

...

input_dist_layer = tfp.layers.MixtureSameFamily(self.K, tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(M,P]))
A = MDN(K, X, Y, input_dist_layer)
```

Where the `component_layer` attribute of `self.dist` is the supplied IndependentNormal layer.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've thought about building it and then accessing _component_layer from the parent class, but this requires knowledge of the output from the LHS layer, whose output size is determined by the params_size attribute.

Comment: The code you have is a little confusing. For example, there's an empty return in the `__init__` methods. What is `params_size` and what will be done with it? (Also, there's a pretty good TFP mailing list that might be able to help you too.)

Comment: Hey @philosofool, thanks for taking a look. This is a real reduced version of the code (hence the `...`) so won't seem logical on its own. Just imagine that I want to extract params_size for some other process inside the `__init__`, but don't want to have to pass in the `component_layer` itself to access it. If it makes more sense, I've updated it to say `self.params_size`. The return void is valid I think, I put it there just to make it more readable.